# prometheus: is it possible to use event number of gauge as a counter?

Tags: grafana, prometheus, metrics, gauge

I use prometheus to monitor a api service. Currently, I use a Counter to count number of requests received and a Gauge for the response time in milliseconds.

I've tried to use something like `count_over_time(response_time_ms[1m])` to count requests during a time range. However, I got result that each point is value of 10.

Why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 4):

`count_over_time(response_time_ms[1m])` will tell you the number of samples, not the number of times your `Gauge` was updated within (what I assume to be) a Java process. Based on the value of 10 you're seeing, I'm assuming your scrape interval is 6 seconds.

For an explanation of why this doesn't work as you would expect it, a `Gauge` is simply a Java object wrapping a `double` value. Every time you set its value, that value changes, but nothing more. There's no count of how many times the value changed or any notification sent to Prometheus that this happened. Prometheus simply polls every 6 seconds and collects whatever value was there at the time (never the wiser that the value changed 15 times since the last time it was collected). This is why gauges are intended to measure single values that go up and down (such as memory utilization: it's now 645 MB, in 6 seconds it's 648 MB, in 12 seconds 543 MB): you know the value constantly changes, but the best you can do is sample it every now and then.

For something like request latency, you should use a `Histogram`: it's basically a counter for the number of observations (i.e. number of requests); a counter for the sum of all observations (i.e. how long all requests put together took); and separate counters for each bucket (i.e. how many requests took less than 1 ms; how many requests took less than 10 ms; etc.). From this you can get an accurate average over any multiple of your scrape interval (i.e. change in total time divided by change in number of requests) as well as estimates for any percentile (including the median). How precise said percentiles are depends on the bucket sizes you choose (and how well they actually match the actual measurements).

Or, if all you're interested in is the number of requests, then a counter that's incremented on every request will be enough. To adjust for counter resets (e.g. job restarts), you should use `increase()` rather than the simple difference suggested above:

```
increase(number_of_requests_total[1m])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count number of requests in some specific time from now (in last 1m in this case) just use

```
number_of_requests_counter - number_of_requests_counter offset 1m
```

If you want to have sth like requests per second, than use

```
rate(number_of_requests_counter[1m])
```

I can tell you  why it's not working with your Gauge, but first of all specify what do you assign to this metric. I mean, do you assing some avarage, last response time, or some other stuff?

For response time you should use Summary or Histogram (more info [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/))